# How to change the position of PrimeNG(v14.2.2) Doughnut Label to left side in Angular(v14.2.12)

Tags: angular, chart.js, primeng

I am trying to align the position of the Doughnut chart labels on the left side. But unable to do so.
I am setting the configuration as follows.

```
this.options = {
      legend: {
        position: 'left',
        align: 'center',
        labels: {
          fontSize: 8  
        }
      },
    };

<p-chart type="doughnut" #pchart [data]="data" width="25vw" height="45vh"[options]="options">
```

I am not able to find any documentation for the same on the PrimNG page. And also check the Chart.js page for the same and applied some configuration but still not able to do.

try the below code also

```
 options: {
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            position: 'left'
          }
        }
      }
```

but the result remains the same. I also check some old post for the same but nothing works.

Comment: The only values working for the position property seem to be 'top' and 'bottom'. Tried them out here --> http://jsfiddle.net/zc5bfj6a/7/ ... If you don't find a solution one way could be to hide the default legend and roll out your own and place it where you desire.

Comment: @SiddharthSeth Earlier, when I was using an older version of PrimeNG(v11) and Angular(v11), the above configuration was working fine, but it is not working after the update. Thanks for the quick reply will try to implement my own title.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to place the title on the left side of the doughnut chart by applying this configuration.

```
this.options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: 'left',
    }
  }
}
```